# Parallel processing stopped working with error: object 'mcinteractive' not found

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio

For a long time I've been successfully running a program which uses parallel processing. a couple of days ago to code stopped working with the error message:

```
    "Error in get("mcinteractive", pkg) : object 'mcinteractive' not 
    found

    traceback()
    8: get("mcinteractive", pkg)

    7: .customized_mcparallel({
    result <- mclapply(X, function(...) {
    res <- FUN(...)
    writeBin(1L, progressFifo)
    return(res)
    }, ..., mc.cores = mc.cores, mc.preschedule = mc.preschedule,
    mc.set.seed = mc.set.seed, mc.cleanup = mc.cleanup, 
    mc.allow.recursive = mc.allow.recursive)
    if ("try-error" %in% sapply(result, class)) {
    writeBin(-1L, progressFifo)
    }
    close(progressFifo)
    result
    })

    6: pbmclapply(1:N, FUN = function(i) {
    max_score = max(scores[i, ])
    topLabels = names(scores[i, scores[i, ] >= max_score - 
    fine.tune.thres])
    if (length(topLabels) == 0) {
    return(names(which.max(scores[i, ])))
    }
```

(I have more traceback if you are interested, but I think it mainly belongs to the "surrounding" code and is not so interesting for the error per se. Tell me if you need it and I'll make an edit!)

I do not know anything about parallel processing, and I haven't been able to understand the issue by digging into the code. From what I've understood, parallel::mcparallel is a function containing the argument mcinteractive for which you can choose TRUE or FALSE. Earlier I got the tip to decrease the number of cores used in the processing. Before I used 16 cores without any issues. After the error started occurring I tried to set the number of cores to both 8 and 1 with the same result. If it is some memory problem I guess I'm in the wrong forum, sorrysorrysorry!! But I only experience problems when using RStudio, which is why I'm writing here. The only other thing that I can think of, that might be related, is that my processing (through RStudio) sometimes gets stuck and the only thing I found is that the RAM memory is full and I have to restart the computer. Then the processing works as usual again. However, this does not help with the new error when using parallel computation.

Do anyone recognize this issue and have any lead to what could be the cause? Is it the code, teh package, studioR or my computer? Any checks I can run? :)

Edit:

Including a short version of the error while searching the code after changing pbmclapply to mclapply.

```
> packageVersion("parallel") 
[1] ‘3.4.4’

> labels = parallel::pbmclapply(1:N, FUN = function(i) {
. . .
+   }, mc.cores = numCores)
Error: 'pbmclapply' is not an exported object from 'namespace:parallel'



> labels = pbmcapply::pbmclapply(1:N, FUN = function(i) {
. . .

+   }, mc.cores = numCores)
Error in get("mcinteractive", pkg) : object 'mcinteractive' not found




> labels = parallel::mclapply(1:N, FUN = function(i) {
. . .
+   }, mc.cores = numCores)
Warning message:
In parallel::mclapply(1:N, FUN = function(i) { :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code



#inside mclapply

> job.res <- lapply(seq_len(cores), inner.do)
Error in mcfork() : could not find function "mcfork"

#inside inner.do

> f <- parallel::mcfork()
Error: 'mcfork' is not an exported object from 'namespace:parallel'
```

Edit 2: came a bit further in my error searching.

I had to add a triple colon before a lot of functions for parallel, meaning that i'm attaching an internal function (?), which in turn should mean that paralell is no longer part of my search path(?)

```
parallel:::mcfork()
parallel:::mc.advance.stream()
parallel:::selectChildren()
parallel:::isChild()

#Had to change .check_ncores(cores) to

parallel::detectCores()
```

Comment: Hi chilifan! I just stumbled across the same problem. It does - for me - only happen using `pbmclapply` but not for `mclapply`, so it seems to be related to the progress bar part, not to the parallel processing part.

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence @Simon ! Thank you! :) I will try this first thing tomorrow and get back with a comment here.

Comment: Hi @chilifan! I tried to further track down the issue. `parallel` does (no longer?) seem to have a function/value "mcinteractive" (which `pbmcapply` tries to import in a private function) . So the issue could be due to an update of the `parallel`-package on which `pbmcapply` is built. I filed am issue [here](https://github.com/kvnkuang/pbmcapply/issues) and wait for the package author's response. Can you confirm that the issue does not appear using `mclapply()`?

Comment: Hi @Simon! I am not sure I can comfirm it 100% since mclapply throws another error, and so far I'm not sure if it tries to use mcinteractive before this error. The problem for me using mcparallel seems to be that mcfork is missing from the parallel package. (but since it is missing, I can't continue to search for errors after that point) I edit my question to include a short version of what I tried.

Comment: Hi @chikifan! The error you report for `parallel::mclapply()` is what I usually get if there is an error my the function that I pass to `mclapply()`. You could check this by running the same command with just `lapply()`. `mcfork()` etc are indeed private functions of the `parallel` package. `pbmcapply` package imports these functions in `.customized_mcparallel()` in `utils.R` as you can see [here](https://rdrr.io/github/kvnkuang/pbmcapply/src/R/utils.R). I am pretty sure that this is where the original error occurs.

Comment: On the [page](https://rdrr.io/github/kvnkuang/pbmcapply/src/R/utils.R) I linked you can also see that `mcfork` is linked to the `parallel` package while `mcinteractive` is not. I confirmed that `mcinteractive` is not part of my version of `parallel`'s namespace by running the commands used in `utils.R`. I tried to install an older version of `parallel` but this didn't work...

Comment: Ok, I will look at the function with lapply, thank you for the tip @Simon . Regarding the pbmcapply, I have waay to little experience to actually understand this. But I agree that when I try to run the different functions from the page you linked, my studio R find all functions (for example mcfork, mcexit, closeStdout etc) except for mcinteractive. So I guess it's not part of my parallel package either. Do you want me to add in with anything in your filed issue on github? :)

Comment: Hi Chilifan! I linked this post in my issue on github but feel free to add a "I have the same issue" to get Kevin Kuang's (package author) attention on it..! Let's hope he find time to check on this!

Comment: will do @simon! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because pbmclapply was updated and now only works with R >3.5, updating R solved my problem.